# SQL: Error (privileges) - SET GLOBAL time_zone

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to execute this SQL command: `SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/Madrid';`

But seems it isn't working because my user doesn't have enough privileges. I checked my user and it have super super privileges..etc

Please check out this video record: **http://screencast.com/t/2aibnDwyf**

What I'm doing wrong? I'm stuck at this issue since 24 hours ago..

Comment: Waiting for cloud-sql@google.com.. I hope they can set this manually.

Comment: Though you already sent an email to 'cloud-sql@google.com' and probably it has been fixed now. However would like to share the link below with you as it encounters the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22894668/how-do-i-persist-mysql-configuration-variables-in-cloudsql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to post the answer: sending an email to cloud-sql@google.com worked.